# Symfony 3.4 vendor autowire

Tags: php, symfony

I've got a problem with symfony 3.4 I'm stuck with. I think i'm not getting symfony autowire right, but I can't find what's causing the error.

I have a fresh installation of symfony with only one addtional package installed: `league/tactician-bundle`

I try to inject it in constructor of DefaultController in the folowing way:

```
/**
 * @var CommandBus
 */
private $bus;

public function __construct(CommandBus $bus)
{
    $this->bus = $bus;
}

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($this->bus);die;
}
```

My services.yml is untouched. When I hit the controller I get following error: `Cannot autowire service "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController": argument "$bus" of method "__construct()" references class "League\Tactician\CommandBus" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this class to the existing "tactician.commandbus.default" service.`

When I define it in my services.yml like this `League\Tactician\CommandBus: '@tactician.commandbus.default'` everything seems to work, but this is very uncomfortable to define every service I need in this way. Is it the only way or am I missing somehting?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like the tactician bundle does not have up to date service definitions.  So the manually added alias is probably your only approach.  Unless there is a CommandBusInterface defined?  You can use bin/console debug:container to see what services are available.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no CommandBusInterface. Is it normal situation for symfony? I see that I can easily inject into constructor all packages which install with symfony, but when it comes to vendors, I have this error.

Comment: Autowire is pretty new.  Quite a few third party bundles will need to catch up.  But adding a few aliases is no big deal.  Might take a look at any issues on the github site for it.

Comment: For what it is worth, I did a fresh Symfony 4.1 install and service League\Tactician\CommandBus was defined.

Comment: Yes you answered your question actually. You need to define alias, because in Tactician Bundle autowiring is turned off. I had the same situation in one of rest apis.

Comment: @revengeance You will find that autowire is turned off in basically every vendor bundle.  Bundles should manually define all their services and aliases needed by the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I'm pretty sure you forgot to register the bundle, that's the only way i could repro the issue. Go to your AppKernel.php and add</strike>

```
new League\Tactician\Bundle\TacticianBundle()
```

in your $bundles array.

L.E. my bad, not the same error message. What version of the bundle are you using? I've got "^1.1" and worked flawless.

Comment: Finally I found the problem thanks to your question. Somehow I've been using old vesrion of bundle, that's why autowiring was not working. Updating solved this problem for me, thanks.